# ExpressJS/Typescript - Unabe to Retrieve ZoneAwarePromise value?

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

**UPDATE 1 STARTS**

Issue is that I am not able to get all the cities and locations in sequence once I draw the FormArray again and this is becuase of the loop only. Anyways, I am new to TS, you might understand much better. Thanks again.

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomValidators } from 'ng2-validation';
import { SharedService } from '../../../layouts/shared-service';
import { MdSnackBar, MdSnackBarConfig, MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MdDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
// Added employee services
import { VehiclePlanService } from '../../../service/vehicle-plan.service';
import { PlanService } from '../../../service/plan.service';
import { LocationService } from '../../../service/location.service';
import { VehicleMakeService } from '../../../service/vehicle-make.service';
import { CommonService } from '../../../service/common.service'; // call the common services
import { PlanInterface } from './plans.interface';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-vehicle-plan',
  templateUrl: './vehicle-plan.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vehicle-plan.component.scss']
})
export class VehiclePlanComponent implements OnInit {

    pageTitle: "Vehicle Plan";
    _id : string = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    public form: FormGroup;

    plansElement = {};   sessionData = {}; activePlans = {}; activeMake = {}; loc = {}; city = {}; locationNames = {};
    activePlanKey = []; activeMakeKey = []; locKey = []; cityKey = []; value = []; planVals = [];
    securityDeposit :  string ; fuleLevel : string; bookinH : string; bookingCycle : string; freeKm : string; grace : string; resVP: string;
    planDetails: string; vehicleDetails: string; vehicleID: string; planID: string; 
    planName: string ; makeName : string;

    constructor(        private fb: FormBuilder,
                        private _sharedService: SharedService, 
                        private router: Router,
                        private route: ActivatedRoute,
                        public snackBar: MdSnackBar,
                        public dialog: MdDialog,
                        private vpService: VehiclePlanService,
                        private plan: PlanService,
                        private locationService: LocationService,
                        private vmService: VehicleMakeService,
                        private commonService : CommonService
                    ) {
                        this._sharedService.emitChange(this.pageTitle);
                        this.commonService.getSession().then((res) => {
                        this.sessionData = res['data'];
                    });
        }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getActivePlans();
        this.getActiveVehicleMake();
        this.getCityForPlan();
        this.getLocForPlan();
        this.planName= '' ; this.makeName = '';
        this.form = this.fb.group({ 
            plan_name:              [null, Validators.required],
            vehicle_make:           [null, Validators.required],
            rate_per_additional_km: [null, Validators.required],
            rate_per_plan:          [null, Validators.required],
            planArray: this.fb.array([
                this.initPlans([]),
            ])
        })

    }

    // Operate vehiclemake to add / edit
    actionVP(model: PlanInterface) {

        let formData = model["value"];
        var pa = model["value"].planArray;

        for(let i=0; i<pa.length;i++) {
            if(pa[i].location_name != null) {
                let vp = {
                    'vehicle_make': [{
                        "id" : formData.vehicle_make,
                        "make_name" : this.vehicleDetails
                    }],
                    'plan_name': [{
                        "id" : formData.plan_name,
                        "plan_name" : this.planDetails
                    }],
                    'location': [{
                        "id" : "1",
                        "location_name" : pa[i].location_name,
                        "city" : pa[i].city,
                        "lat" : "0.00",
                        "long" : "0.00"
                    }],
                    'plan_rate': (pa[i].rate_plan != null) ? pa[i].rate_plan : formData.rate_per_plan,
                    'total_free_km': (pa[i].total_free_km != null) ? pa[i].total_free_km : this.freeKm,
                    'additional_km_charges': (pa[i].additional_km_charges != null) ? pa[i].additional_km_charges : formData.rate_per_additional_km,
                    'minimum_hours': (pa[i].minimum_hours != null) ? pa[i].minimum_hours : this.bookinH,
                    'booking_cycle': (pa[i].booking_cycle != null) ? pa[i].booking_cycle : this.bookingCycle,
                    'rate_fuel_level': (pa[i].rate_fuel_level != null) ? pa[i].rate_fuel_level : this.fuleLevel,
                    'grace_period': (pa[i].grace_period != null) ? pa[i].grace_period : this.grace,
                    'security_deposit': (pa[i].security_deposit != null) ? pa[i].security_deposit : this.securityDeposit,
                    "organization" : [{
                        "id" : "1",
                        "name" : "Driven"
                    }],
                    'modified_date': new Date()
                };

                // SAVE DATA START
                if(this.route.snapshot.params['id']) {
                    this.updateVP(this.route.snapshot.params['id'], vp);
                } else {
                    this.saveVP(vp);
                }
                // SAVE DATA END

            }
        }
    }

    // Insert data to vehiclemake
    saveVP(vp) {
        // Build data JSON
        vp['created_date'] = new Date();
        this.vpService.saveVehiclePlan(vp).then((result) => {
            let id = result['data']['_id'];
            this.openSnackBar("Saved vehicle plan successfully", "");
            this.router.navigate(['/driven/vehicle-plan']);
        }, (err) => {
            this.openSnackBar("Something went wrong! vehicle plan not saved", "");
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    // Update vehiclemake details
    updateVP(id, vp) {
        this.vpService.updateVehiclePlan(id, vp).then((result) => {
            let id = result['data']['_id'];
            this.openSnackBar("Updated vehicle plan successfully", "");
            this.router.navigate(['/driven/vehicle-plan']);
        }, (err) => {
            this.openSnackBar("Something went wrong! vehicle plan not updated", "");
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    // Get the all active plans
    getActivePlans() {
        this.plan.getActivePlans().then((res) => {
         if(res['status'] == 'success'){
            this.activePlans = res['data'];     
            this.activePlanKey = Object.keys(this.activePlans);
          }else{
              this.openSnackBar(res['data']['message'], "");
          }         
        }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
        });
    }

    // Get the all active plans
    getActiveVehicleMake() {
        this.vmService.getActiveVehicleMake().then((res) => {
         if(res['status'] == 'success'){
            this.activeMake = res['data'];      
            this.activeMakeKey = Object.keys(this.activeMake);
          }else{
              this.openSnackBar(res['data']['message'], "");
          }         
        }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
        });
    }
    // Get the all Locations for plans gruped by city
    getCityForPlan() {
        this.locationService.getCityForPlan().then((res) => {
         if(res['status'] == 'success'){
            this.city = res['data'];        
            this.cityKey = Object.keys(this.city);
          }else{
              this.openSnackBar(res['data']['message'], "");
          }         
        }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
        });
    }

    async getLocForPlan() {
        let res = await this.locationService.getLocForPlan();
        if(res['status'] == 'success') {
            this.loc = res['data'];
            this.locKey = Object.keys(this.loc);
            this.addEditValues();
        } else {
            this.openSnackBar(res['data']['message'], "");
        }
    }

    // used to display the alert message 
    openSnackBar(message: string, action: string) {
        this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
            duration: 2000,
        });
    }

    initPlans(planVals) {
        //console.log(planVals);
        return this.fb.group({
            city_name:              [planVals['city_name']],
            city :                  [planVals['city']],
            is_active:              [planVals['is_active']],
            location_name:          [planVals['location_name']],
            rate_plan:              [planVals['rate_plan']],
            total_free_km:          [planVals['total_free_km']],
            additional_km_charges:  [planVals['additional_km_charges']],
            minimum_hours:          [planVals['minimum_hours']],
            booking_cycle:          [planVals['booking_cycle']],
            rate_fuel_level:        [planVals['rate_fuel_level']],
            grace_period:           [planVals['grace_period']],
            security_deposit:       [planVals['security_deposit']]
        });
    }

    addEditValues() {
        let len = this.locKey.length;
        const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['planArray'];
        if(len) { control.removeAt(0); }
        for(let i=0;i<len;i++) {
            // DEFAULT NULL
            this.planVals['city'] = null;
            this.planVals['location_name'] = null;
            this.planVals['is_active'] = null;
            this.planVals['rate_plan'] = null;
            this.planVals['total_free_km'] = null;
            this.planVals['additional_km_charges'] = null;
            this.planVals['minimum_hours'] = null;
            this.planVals['booking_cycle'] = null;
            this.planVals['rate_fuel_level'] = null;
            this.planVals['grace_period'] = null;
            this.planVals['security_deposit'] = null;
            // DEFAULT NULL
            this.planVals['city_name'] = this.loc[i]._id[0];
            let lenInner = this.loc[i].locations.length;
            for(let k=0;k<lenInner;k++) {
                if(this.loc[i].locations[k].is_active) {
                    // UPDATED DATA FROM DB
                    if(this.planID && this.vehicleID) {
                        this.planVals['city'] = this.loc[i].locations[k].city[0];
                        this.planVals['location_name'] = this.loc[i].locations[k].location_name;
                        this.getVPDetails(this.planID,this.vehicleID,this.planVals['location_name'],this.planVals['city']).then((res: any) => {
                            console.log(res);
                            if(res['status'] == 'success') {
                                if(k==0) {
                                    this.planVals['city_name'] = this.loc[i]._id[0];
                                    control.push(this.initPlans(this.planVals)); //#### PUSH INTO FORMARRAY ####
                                }
                                // FROM DB
                                this.planVals['rate_plan'] = res['data'][0]['plan_rate'];
                                this.planVals['total_free_km'] = res['data'][0]['total_free_km'];
                                this.planVals['additional_km_charges'] = res['data'][0]['additional_km_charges'];
                                this.planVals['minimum_hours'] = res['data'][0]['minimum_hours'];
                                this.planVals['booking_cycle'] = res['data'][0]['booking_cycle'];
                                this.planVals['rate_fuel_level'] = res['data'][0]['rate_fuel_level'];
                                this.planVals['grace_period'] = res['data'][0]['grace_period'];
                                this.planVals['security_deposit'] = res['data'][0]['security_deposit'];
                                // FROM DB
                                this.planVals['city_name'] = null;
                                this.planVals['is_active'] = this.loc[i].locations[k].is_active;
                                this.planVals['city'] = this.loc[i].locations[k].city[0];
                                this.planVals['location_name'] = this.loc[i].locations[k].location_name;
                                control.push(this.initPlans(this.planVals)); //#### PUSH INTO FORMARRAY ####
                            } else {
                                if(k==0) {
                                    this.planVals['city_name'] = this.loc[i]._id[0];
                                    control.push(this.initPlans(this.planVals)); //#### PUSH INTO FORMARRAY ####
                                }
                                // BLANK DATA AT FIRST
                                this.planVals['rate_plan'] = null;
                                this.planVals['total_free_km'] = null;
                                this.planVals['additional_km_charges'] = null;
                                this.planVals['minimum_hours'] = null;
                                this.planVals['booking_cycle'] = null;
                                this.planVals['rate_fuel_level'] = null;
                                this.planVals['grace_period'] = null;
                                this.planVals['security_deposit'] = null;
                                // BLANK DATA AT FIRST
                                this.planVals['city_name'] = null;
                                this.planVals['city'] = this.loc[i].locations[k].city[0];
                                this.planVals['is_active'] = this.loc[i].locations[k].is_active;
                                this.planVals['location_name'] = this.loc[i].locations[k].location_name;
                                control.push(this.initPlans(this.planVals)); //#### PUSH INTO FORMARRAY ####
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        if(k==0) {
                            this.planVals['city_name'] = this.loc[i]._id[0];
                            control.push(this.initPlans(this.planVals)); //#### PUSH INTO FORMARRAY ####
                        }
                        // BLANK DATA AT FIRST
                        this.planVals['rate_plan'] = null;
                        this.planVals['total_free_km'] = null;
                        this.planVals['additional_km_charges'] = null;
                        this.planVals['minimum_hours'] = null;
                        this.planVals['booking_cycle'] = null;
                        this.planVals['rate_fuel_level'] = null;
                        this.planVals['grace_period'] = null;
                        this.planVals['security_deposit'] = null;
                        // BLANK DATA AT FIRST
                        this.planVals['city_name'] = null;
                        this.planVals['city'] = this.loc[i].locations[k].city[0];
                        this.planVals['is_active'] = this.loc[i].locations[k].is_active;
                        this.planVals['location_name'] = this.loc[i].locations[k].location_name;
                        control.push(this.initPlans(this.planVals)); //#### PUSH INTO FORMARRAY ####
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    removeFormArray() {
        this.planVals = [];
        const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['planArray'];
        for (var i = control.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            this.removeInput(i);
        }
    }

    removeInput(i: number) {
        const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['planArray'];
        control.removeAt(i);
    }

    async getVPDetails(pid, vid, locname, cityname): Promise<any> {
        return await this.vpService.getVehiclePlansInfo({plan_id: pid, make_id: vid, loc: locname, city: cityname});
    }

    // used to populate the  default security deposit & fule level
    selectVM(value){
       this.vmService.showVehicleMake(value['value']).then((res) => {           
            this.securityDeposit = res['data']['base_security_deposit'];
            this.fuleLevel = res['data']['rate_per_fuel_level'];
            this.makeName = value['value'];
            this.vehicleID = res['data']['_id'];
            this.vehicleDetails = res['data']['brand_name'] + ' ' + res['data']['make_name'] + ' ' + res['data']['model_name'];
            this.getVehiclePlan();
            return false;
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
    // used to prepopulate the default value min booking h, h/ booking cycle, free km, grace time
    //bookinH : string; bookingCycle : string; freeKm : string; grace : string;
    selectPlan(value) {
        this.plan.getPlansInfo(value['value']).then((res) => {
            this.bookinH = res['data']['min_booking_hours'];
            this.bookingCycle = res['data']['hours_per_booking_cycle'];
            this.freeKm = res['data']['free_km_per_booking_cycle'];
            this.grace = res['data']['grace_period_in_hours'];
            this.planName = value['value'];
            this.planDetails = res['data']['plan_name'];
            this.planID = res['data']['_id'];
            this.getVehiclePlan();
            return false;
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
    // get the all plans on change of plans and vehicle make
    getVehiclePlan(){       
        if(this.planName != ''  && this.makeName != '' ) {
            //const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['planArray'];
            //control.controls = [];
            this.removeFormArray();
            this.addEditValues();
        }
    }

    // update the plan screen with default values
    updateDefaultValue(){
        var rate_plan = $('.rate_per_plan').val();      var additional_km_charges = $('.rate_per_additional_km').val();
        var security_deposit = this.securityDeposit;    var grace_period = this.grace;        
        var rate_fuel_level = this.fuleLevel;           var booking_cycle = this.bookingCycle;        
        var minimum_hours = this.bookinH;               var total_free_km = this.freeKm;

        $('.security_deposit, .grace_period, .rate_fuel_level, .booking_cycle, .minimum_hours, .additional_km_charges, .total_free_km, .rate_plan').each(function(){
            $('.security_deposit').val(security_deposit);
            $('.grace_period').val(grace_period);
            $('.rate_fuel_level').val(rate_fuel_level);
            $('.booking_cycle').val(booking_cycle);
            $('.minimum_hours').val(minimum_hours);
            $('.additional_km_charges').val(additional_km_charges);
            $('.total_free_km').val(total_free_km);
            $('.rate_plan').val(rate_plan);
        });
        return false;
    }

    checkAllLoc(value){
        var val = $('#'+value).val();
        if(val == "true"){
            $('.'+value).prop('checked', true); 
            $('#'+value).val("false");
        } else {
            $('.'+value).prop('checked', false); 
            $('#'+value).val("true");
        }
    }

    uncheckParent(value){
        $('#'+value).prop('checked', false);
        $('#'+value).val("true");
    }

}
```

### **UPDATE 1 ENDS**

I am using TypeScript in MeanStack and using a function with **async** because it was not working in sequential order

```
// Calling Function (In Main.ts file)
let rs = getVPDetails("2132");

// Function Definition (In Main.ts file)
async getVPDetails(pid) {
    let res = await this.vpService.getPlansInfo({plan_id: pid});
    return res;
}

// Middle Ware (IN service.ts file)
  getPlansInfo(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.post('/vehicle-plan/plan-info', data)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(res);
          }, (err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
    });
  }
```

I am getting the exact value while returning res (in "return res;") as I require. But in rs (Where I call), I am getting a value like this:

ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}

In __zone_symbol__value I am having my data as I require but by no means I am able to access it. I know that I am breaking the Promise object but how can I resolve it exactly when I dont want to use then() in getVPDetails();

Please let me know what am I missing OR how can I get the data I require.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you add `async` to a method, it will *always* return a `Promise<T>`. Where `T` is whatever you return, `string`, `void`, w/e.

That's the whole idea of `async`, and the only way to get the right value is to use `then`. Your `async` here is actually not necessary, because you are returning another `Promise`, but that's beside the point :)

Best would be to use type hints, otherwise there is no real reason to use `TypeScript`. This way the compiler gives you the hints and errors, and you would have been notified of your error:

```
getVPDetails("2132").then((rs: PlanInfo) => {
    // here you will have your `rs`
});

// Function Definition (using async/await as demonstration)
async getVPDetails(pid): Promise<PlanInfo> {
    return await this.vpService.getPlansInfo({plan_id: pid});
}

// Middle Ware
getPlansInfo(data): Promise<PlanInfo> {
    return this.http.post('/vehicle-plan/plan-info', data)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Wow, what a beautiful way of defining the methods. I am new to TypeScript and hence did not knew these aspects of it. You saved my day, however I am just getting one issues that PlanInfo (In :Promise<PlanInfo>) is not defined. Exact error in console is:

Cannot find name 'PlanInfo'.

Comment: PlanInfo is a type I made up. You should replace it with the class it actually receives or just with `any` :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @PierreDuc for the reply, but actually this is returning the same thing and I am not getting things in sequential order now. Actually my function getVPDetails is in for loop and it was not working in sequential order even when everything is fine, hence I used the way I tried for in the starting. 

getVPDetails("2132").then((rs: PlanInfo) => {
    // here you will have your `rs`
});

What can I do for sequential execution please?

Comment: Can you post your entire code, including the for loop. Just bear in mind that you can't make an `async` flow sequential. JavaScript and with it TypeScript is event driven

Comment: I have updated the code @PierreDuc in the main question itself. Please see if it can help.

Comment: By default it lets me the proper linear flow and prints cities and location properly in sequence, but when I call getVPDetails, it does not gives resultset in sequence. It has started giving me with the code I pasted but the result was a Promise Object ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}

Comment: You can check how its working on 

http://ec2-13-126-164-254.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3200/
Username - rolando@enmovil.ingfd
Password - ptgo80k9

Then you can go to Plans > Vehicle Plans
Direct URL - http://ec2-13-126-164-254.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3200/#/driven/vehicle-plan

All is fine in sequence once the page loads, but when we change Plan and Vehicle Make Dropdowns at the top, it mess up the sequence. This is what I am talking about. Hope it helps.

Data is that populates in these text boxes. 
(Vehicle Make - Hyundai & Plan- Fuel)